# How to click an element using javascript in selenium robot framework script?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click an element using javascript (this is for selenium robot framework script). But it is throwing an error

```
unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list)
```

Can you please help me correct my statement.

Execute Javascript -->>

```
document.evaluate('\\span[text()='Participant']', document, null, FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).click()
```

As you can see in the above statement, I want javascript to click element that has 'Participant' text (the xpath doesn't have any id or any other attributes except text). If I have made any errors in the code/statement, can you please help me write the correct code/statement.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many mistakes in your `javaScript` :-

- [`xPath`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) start with `/` which means **Selects from the root node** or `//` which means **Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are**
- if you are using `''` for whole `xpath` as string then use `""` to other string inside `xpath` expression, or  using `""` for whole `xpath` as string then use `''` for other string inside `xpath` expression
- read [`Document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) syntax how to use it in `javascript`.

So after all of these point you should try as below with correct `javascript` :-

```
document.evaluate("//span[text()='Participant']", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).click();
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Thank you for your updated code. I tried to execute script with your changed code but got the following error.   unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn(<anonymous>:875:140)     at Object.injectedScript._evaluateAndWrap(<anonymous>:808:34)   at Object.injectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)

Comment: @Yogi could you share how to call this javascript using selenium??

Comment: @Yogi this error coming due to `""`...you should try to use JavaScript into your method as  `document.evaluate(\"//span[text()='Participant']\", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).click();`

Comment: I want to keep you posted that your code worked in the browser console. but it isn't executing through selenium robot framework. Thanks a lot for your help and time. It was really a great help.

Comment: @Yogi you welcome.. glad to help you..:).but why is it not executing through selenium robot framework?? could you share how to call this javascript using selenium robot framework??